# How to increase padding margin between rshiny dashboard sidebar menuitems?

Tags: css, r, shiny, sidebar

I am new to Rshiny Dashboard creation and want to increase the padding/margin between the icon and the tabname as appearing in the sidebar menu of my Rshiny dashboard. How can this be done?
Please provide help.

```
Dashboard_Sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(tags$head(tags$style(HTML('

                            /* Sidebar */
                            .skin-blue .main-sidebar {
                            background-color: #d3bf96;
                            font-size: 16px;
                            font-family: "Roboto";
                            }
                            
                            /* Sidebar other items */
                            .skin-blue .main-sidebar .sidebar a{
                            color: #000000;
                            padding-left: 20px;
                            }
                            
                            /* Sidebar when active/hover */
                            .skin-blue .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu a:hover , 
                            .skin-blue .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu .active a{
                            background-color: #000000;
                            color: #ffffff;
                            padding-top: 10px;
                            padding-left: 20px;
                            display: block;
                            border-color: transparent;
                            }
                            '))),

                        width = 250,
                        sidebarMenu(
                                menuItem("Introduction",tabName = "introduction", icon = icon("file-alt", "fa-lg fa-fw"))
))
```

Comment: Did you try with display: inline-block instead of display: block;?

Comment: Kindly share some reproducible code

Comment: Thanks for your reply. inline-block reduce the total block size. Also this is the css code. the next is just menuitems (added in the code).